# CTE and tablename as parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

In SQL Server 2008, I have stored procedure containing a CTE

```
;with t1 as (select * from db..tablename where …)
Select * from t1;
```

I want to use `tablename` as one of the stored procedure parameters.

Please note the size of `T1` turns out to be too big to use something like

```
Exec(‘select * into #temptable from db..’+’tablename’+’ where …’)
```

There have been similar questions and answers but none of them seems to help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain this a bit detail? "Please note the size of T1 turns out to be too big to use something like Exec(‘select * into #temptable from db..’+’tablename’+’ where …’)"

Comment: Why don't they seem to help?. Pass the table name in as a parameter. Check that it's as table name, better still a table name this should be used with, then build some sql using the table name not the parameter and execute it. It's painful, because you should try real hard not to have to do it...

Comment: The dataset of first sub query, T1, is pretty large. If this was not the case then I would have sent output of t1 into temp table.

Comment: Some one down voted the question and did not feel need to explain it. It just tells me type of person s/he is.

Answer (score 0):

I love using CTE's.  They are such a great utility!

For this particular problem might I suggest against it. Given that you are "transporting" a table worth of data to another stored proc I think you should handle it a bit differently.

Consider your first proc:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SomeTempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP SomeTempTable;

SELECT
    *
INTO SomeTempTable
FROM
YourOtherTable

EXEC YourSecondProcedureName
```

Please note you'll need to be mindfull of the scope you want for your table.  I haven't included working code until you make that consideration.  More information can be found here: [Temp Table Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331807/temporary-table-scope)

Also note that the "YourSecondProcedureName" does not take a table value now.  Instead (and with the right scope) you can just call out of your temp table by name.  Its also considered best practice to drop your temp tables when done though there are some mechanisms in sql server depending on version that can do some of it for you.  Again scope scope scope.

Hope this helps!

Matt